# Tengo un problema con boostrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Tengo mis columnas y en telefono se colican una abajo de la otra y en computadoras uno alado de la otra, le ouse my-2 y mx-2 para que tenga margenes entre ellas, cuando la pantalla es chica y se colican una debajo de la otra hacen que el mx-2 las empuje hacia la derecha y salgan de la pantalla, aqui les dejo el proyecto.

```html
<div class="container contenedor">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg my-2 mx-2">
                <i class="fas fa-palette"></i>
                <h4>
                    Hola mundo s
                </h4>
                <p>
                    equidem fermentum tincidunt sociosqu quaestio sea eripuit taciti necessitatibus recteque intellegebat dicunt
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg my-2 mx-2">
                <i class="fas fa-palette"></i>
                <h4>
                    Hola mundo s
                </h4>
                <p>
                    equidem fermentum tincidunt sociosqu quaestio sea eripuit taciti necessitatibus recteque intellegebat dicunt
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg my-2 mx-2">
                <i class="fas fa-palette"></i>
                <h4>
                    Hola mundo s
                </h4>
                <p>
                    equidem fermentum tincidunt sociosqu quaestio sea eripuit taciti necessitatibus recteque intellegebat dicunt
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que lleves cursos de CSS o de flexbox y css grid, pero utiliza la propiedad [gap](https://mdbootstrap.com/how-to/bootstrap/columns-space/), quita todos tus "my-2 mx-2" y en tu clase "row" agregarle "g-2" quedando asi "row g-2" y listo.

Comment: Gracias, ahora tiene un margen cuando estan uno abajo del otro, pero cuando entro en pc y se colocan uno alado del otro no se añade los margenes laterales y estan pegados.